# NSNumberFormatter numberFromString doesn't return number from currency string

Tags: ios5, nsnumberformatter

```
numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle;    
NSLog(_priceTF.text);
NSNumber *price = [numberFormatter numberFromString:_priceTF.text];
NSLog([price stringValue]);
```

Console output: 25 kr

P.S. : price is nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, I get NSNumber so (but that's weird):

```
NSString *priceNoCurrency = [_priceTF.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:numberFormatter.currencySymbol withString:@""];
NSNumber *price = @(priceNoCurrency.integerValue);
```